# Google Map Routing Syntax

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios4

can someone please explain to me how does the syntax looks like if I wanna write the google map routing?

```
http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=San+Francisco,+CA&saddr=cupertino
```

Let say now I dont want use places' name as my input, I have source/destination coordinate, how should I put it?

For example:
Destination coordinate = (12,32)
Source coordinate = (32, 24)

```
   http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=12,32,saddr=32,34
```

But the above code doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 NSString *urlstring=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f",32.0,24.0,12.0,32.0];
```

In general terms:-

```
 NSString *urlstring=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f",sourcelocation.latitude,sourcelocation.longitude,destinationlocation.latitude,destinationlocation.longitude];
```

Comment: @Cadrick I hope your problem must be solved using this line of code.